# threejs error when obj file are loaded

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having troubles with obj files downloaded from internet.
All these files renders as this pic:
[Obj pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Zsk.png)

I'm using the standard OBJLoader.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( objURL, function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

I can not figure out what might be wrong.

EDIT:
This is my complete loader:

```
    loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);

    loader.load(filePath, function (object) {
        object.traverse(function (child) {

            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                if (count == 1) {
                    child.material = material;
                    var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(child);
                    xyzSizes = box.size();

                    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                    geometry = child.geometry;

                    var volume = myVolume(geometry);
                    THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);

                    scene.add(child);
                    DOM.children(".loading").remove();
                    myObj = child;
                    myObj.name = 'GL' + idfile;
                    maxSize = Math.max(xyzSizes.x, xyzSizes.y, xyzSizes.z);

                    maxSize = 2 / maxSize;
                    DOM.parent().find('.volumeVal').html(myRound(volume, 2));
                    DOM.parent().find('.sizesVal').html('x: ' + myRound(xyzSizes.x, 3) + ' y: ' + myRound(xyzSizes.y, 3) + ' z: ' + myRound(xyzSizes.z, 3));
                    console.log('il volume è: ' + volume + ' e gli assi xyz sono: ' + xyzSizes.x, xyzSizes.y, xyzSizes.z);
                    if (maxSize == 0)
                        maxSize = 0.1;
                    object.scale.set(maxSize, maxSize, maxSize);
                } else {
                    child.material = transparent;
                }
            } else {

            }
            count++;
        });


    });
```

Comment: if i try to load the same object converted in stl or other obj files created with blender they are shown correctly

Comment: According to the documentation, the default material when using this loader is a `MeshLambertMaterial`. Do you have a light in your scene?

Comment: @Mr_Pouet Yes i have lights and i'm using a phong material(but the error occur also with the LambertMaterial)

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears fine.

Are you testing in Firefox and is your objUrl set properly?

At the moment, I am thinking that maybe your objUrl is set to https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Zsk.png somewhere and it isn't geting changed back to your desired image.

Another thing, are the obj files downloaded from the internet placed in the same folder location as the ones you created using blender?

I used your code with http://tf3dm.com/download-page.php?url=high-poly-male-2014   and had the Zuccarello.obj next to my index.html

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( "Zuccarello.obj", function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

If none of this helps, please share a bit more code so I can see it, particularly anything involving your objURL variable.

Comment: i'm using chrome for testing and i think that objUrl is correct because it is passed by a function that upload a file in the webserver root and pass the new path of the file. it works with stl object(with his loader) and other obj files passed to my scripts in the same way. so i think that's a problem of the object. but i cannot figure it

Comment: Very strange and interesting. Do you see any console errors using chrome? Also, just to verify the objurl, please put a console.log(objUrl); statement before the load to ensure the objUrl is correct and let me know what the console says.

Comment: i checked my console and there are not errors, i logged the objUl and it's correct, any other ideas? oh, i also have an AxisHelper in my scene. it works well with files that are correctly shown but with the obj file that give this error it is shown but  the mesh disappear.

Comment: i just discovered that if i import the file in blender and than i re-export it in obj format, when i reload it the loader work fine. So there is something wrong with the file... any idea? Could be a wrong format?